# Why does this RewriteRule produce infinite recursion?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to do rather basic URL rewriting but cannot get it running properly.

I want to redirect all requests to `wordpress.foobar.com` to a local symlinked WordPress installation via my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^wordpress\.foobar\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /html/wordpress/$1 [L]
```

While I can perfectly access `foobar.com/html/wordpress`, visiting `wordpress.foobar.com` will raise a 500 Internal Server Error.

Apache's error log will contain the following:

```
[error] [client 12.123.123.123] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to
probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get
 a backtrace.
```

When I enable debug LogLevel I can see that Apache is trying to rewrite `favicon.ico` infinitely, always appending another layer of `/html/wordpress/` until the recursion limit is reached.

What's wrong with this rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the error `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to
probable configuration error.`, ask yourself the question: How did I design my rules to terminate at some point, and why does it not terminate.

In your case, your rule matches everything. The status of the condition will not change either, so if your rule matches one time, it will match an infinite amount of times. This might work on some setups if you rewrite to a file that does exist. It is a safer bet to just prevent it from rewriting more than once by testing if `/html/wordpress/` already is in the url:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^wordpress\.foobar\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/html/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /html/wordpress/$1 [L]
```

Besides this, I am not sure if wordpress will recognize your rewritten url. That is for you to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^wordpress\.foobar\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/html/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /html/wordpress/$1 [L]
```

With `-f` and `-d` test, you do not redirect existing files and directories. This way, you avoid the problems with `favicon.ico` (if you have that file, I suggest you add if this is not the case).